# Weird behaviour of deleting row in table view using core data in iOS7

Tags: uitableview, core-data, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

I am testing the use of UILongPressGestureRecognizer in my iOS app. This is the scenario:
1.- One tableview controller showing records from a core data entity.
2.- One method to delete row from the core data entity (normal use of commitEditingStyle), used to delete the selected row from the core data entity.
3.- One UILongPressGestureRecognizer method to long-press the row, to fire an alert view, and to also delete the selected row from the core data entity.

This is the concerning code:
Point 2.-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
  {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
      NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      abort();
    }
      NSError *error1 = nil;
      if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error1])
      {
          NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error1, [error userInfo]);
          abort();
      }
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"To-Do Deleted" message: @"You have marked To-Do as deleted...!" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
      [alert release];
      [self.tableView reloadData];
  }   
}
```

This method works as expected. After touching the red DELETE button, the alert view is shown, the performfetch executed and the table reloaded, not showing the last deleted object. After that, executing the app again, demonstrates that the deleted row is really deleted and no more shown.

Executing the point 3.-, shows the same behaviour as point 2.-, except that after executing the app a second time, the deleted row appears again, that means that it is not deleted from core data. This is the code for point 3.-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
  }

    //long press

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.00;
    //seconds
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];




  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

  return cell;
}


-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil)
        NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
    else
    {

        if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
            //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
        }
        else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Announcement" message: @"You have long-pressed the row...!" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.");


            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
            [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
            NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);

            // Update ToDoStatus
            NSError *error1 = nil;
            if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error1])
            {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error1, [error1 userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
        }

    }
}
```

I am not able to find the reason for the unexpected behaviour. Any help is welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps neglecting to save the `NSManagedObjectContext`? That would explain why the item goes away, but then reappears on a later launch.

Aside: this line in your first sniipet

```
      NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error1, [error userInfo]);
```

refers to both `error1` and `error`; a bug, but not the cause of your problem.

Comment: That is, you are right. Thank you very much, I was handling  with this issue all day long....